# Changes from two branches in 1?

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

```
git commit -m "my changes"
git push origin change-1
```

I ran the above code to commit my changes and push them to my branch called "change-1".

```
git checkout change-2
```

I ran the above line to switch from my branch to a colleagues branch and I have this problem where the source code in my IDE (Intellij) contains my changes from my branch "change-1" and my colleagues branch "change-2". Why is this? I though the whole idea of switching branches is that you can work on somebody's changes without mixing it with your own?

```
git checkout master
```

When I run the above command from change-1 branch, it lists all the files I have updated in change-1 with an M in the leftmost column. Why is that?

Comment: Probably someone merged the branches already into change-2, or change-2 was created initially with change-1 as base. Check the git log.

Comment: @edb500 Why is this question related to [java]?

Comment: @Vertexwahn - java tag can be removed

Comment: Did you `git add` the files before committing? It looks like you committed only some of the changes. The changes not committed are still in your working tree only. They are not modified by `git checkout` **if** the checkout doesn't encounter conflicts.

Comment: @axiac, the problem was I was working off of master before I created my branch. So there were still changes sitting on master, so all I did was revert the changes sitting on master.

Comment: The not yet committed changes are not on a branch. They are only in the working tree. They survive to `git checkout` unless they conflict with the changes introduced by the new branch. This is a feature when it is used correctly. Read about [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)